# Why EL in a script getting executed always on when the page is renderred

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a script element within a xhtml page, In this script I try to call a method on a bean using EL. I am not understanding why this EL is evaluated on page render.
I am using primeface 3.5 and JSF 2.x.
 here is the code

```
<h:form>
   <p:socket channel="/channel" onMessage="handleMessage"></p:socket>
</h:form>

<script>
  function handleMessage(data){
    var update=data.update;

    if(update){
      #{bean.method()};
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: is evaluated or is not evaluated ? Please post your bean code as well.

Comment: everytime page is loaded bean.method() is called

Comment: because each time the page is parsed the EL is evaluated. you can otherwise (assuming your backing bean is not `request` scoped) create a flag in `bean.method()`  to check if the method was invoked at least once and a variable to hold the return value of the method.

Answer (score 0):

EL expressions are evaluated in different phases of **every** JSF request, e.g. action method invocations in INVOKE_APPLICATION, rendered attributes in RENDER_RESPONSE phase, validators in PROCESS_VALIDATION. The results are kept in the jsf view.

What your code actually does is to call bean.method() in the JSF lifecycle and outputs the return value of your method in the output HTML file. Javascript is not executed during JSF processing on the server side but only on the client side, so your if-condition doesn't prevent server side processing.

What you probably want to do is to only call your bean method when the javascript is executed from the client side.

You can use the primefaces [p:remoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) component to accomplish that. It exposes a javascript function as a wrapper for a java bean method.

```
<h:form>
   <p:socket channel="/channel" onMessage="handleMessage"></p:socket>
   <p:remoteCommand name="methodWrapper" actionListener="#{bean.method()}" />
</h:form>

<script>
   function handleMessage(data){
   var update=data.update;

   if(update){
      methodWrapper();
   }
}
</script>
```